# A discrete random variable has the PMF of x/15 for x = 1,2,3,4,5 and p(x) = 0 for all other values. $Z = 3X^2 +1$. what is Var(Z)?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

> A discrete random variable has the PMF of $x/15$ for $x \in\{ 1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $p(x) = 0$ for all other values.
>       $Z = 3X^2 +1$. what is $\mathsf {Var}(Z)$?

When I solve for $\mathsf E(Z)$ I get $3[1/225 + 4/225 + 9/225 + 16/225 + 25/225] + 1$.

Then when I solve for $\mathsf E(Z^2)$ I get $3^2[(1/225)^2 + (4/225)^2 + (9/225)^2 + (16/225)^2 + (25/225)^2] + 1^2$.

Then $\mathsf {Var}(Z) = \mathsf {Var}(aX+b) = 3^2(Var(Z))$.

Which $\mathsf {Var}(Z) = \mathsf E(Z^2) - (\mathsf E(Z))^2$.

When I plug in the value I get a negative value. HELP! I know variance is a non-negative number.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** $\color{navy}{\text{The original post has been updated.  Added new text to also answer the amended post.}}$

Why are you squaring the probability to find $\mathsf E(Z)$?   You just need: $$\mathsf E(3X+1) = 1 + 3 \sum_{x=1}^5 \frac {x^2}{15}$$

$$\color{navy}{\mathsf E(3X^2+1) = 1 + 3 \sum_{x=1}^5 \frac {x^3}{15}}$$

Your formula for $\mathsf E[(3X+1)^2]$ is further erroneous.   You have attempted to find $\mathsf E[(3X)^2+1]$ instead.    What you need is:

$$\mathsf E((3X+1)^2) = \sum_{x=1}^{5}\frac{(3x+1)^2x}{15}$$

$$\color{navy}{\mathsf E((3X^2+1)^2) = \sum_{x=1}^{5}\frac{(3x^2+1)^2x}{15}}$$

Comment: OP's formula is completely incorrect, it is not even formula for $\mathsf E[(3X)^2+1]$ as his probabilities do not sum to 1.

Comment: Yeap, he's compounded errors.

Comment: The person who edited my post forgot to put 3X^2+1. This is where I got my solution. Can you please relook at it?

Comment: There was no $3X^2+1$ in the original post, but whatever. Your amended post still doesn't make sense.  The random variable $X$ is squared, but there is no reason to square the probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I do not undestand, where you get $\frac{1}{225}$. Lets count $EX$
$$EX=1\frac{1}{15}+2\frac{2}{15}+3\frac{3}{15}+4\frac{4}{15}+5\frac{5}{15}=\frac{55}{15},$$
and now count 
$$EX^2=\sum_{i=1}^{5}i^2\frac{i}{15}=\frac{225}{15},$$
therefore
$$var(X)=\frac{225}{15}-\frac{55^2}{15^2}>1.5$$
Now can you do the same for $Z$.

Comment: Instead of $\sum_x x\;p(x) = \sum_x \frac {x^2}{15}$ he's tried $\sum_x {(\frac{x}{15})}^2$ for ... unknown reasons.

Comment: Yep, I noticed, we've just commented each other answers:-)

Comment: There was an error in the reediting in my post. Can you relook at my post?

Comment: So can you count it using the mine approach?